# systemd Exec format error

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a java file which I'm trying to install as a service. But I'm getting errors. Below is the contents of my file and errors. I'm running Debian 8.

```
[Unit]
Description=App1Manager
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/jsvc -user root -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/local/myapp/bin/Manager.jar -pidfile /var/run/app1manager.pid

Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With either the below I get the following error:

```
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /lib/systemd/system/myapp1 
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug /etc/init.d/myapp1 

/etc/init.d/myapp1: line 1: [Unit]: command not found
/etc/init.d/myapp1: line 6: [Service]: command not found
/etc/init.d/myapp1: line 7: -user: command not found
/etc/init.d/myapp1: line 10: [Install]: command not found


Aug 12 12:04:39 debian systemd[3903]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/myapp1: Exec format error
-- Subject: Process /etc/init.d/myapp1 could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- The process /etc/init.d/myapp1 could not be executed and failed.
--
-- The error number returned while executing this process is 8.
Aug 12 12:04:39 debian systemd[1]: myapp1.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Aug 12 12:04:39 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start (null).
-- Subject: Unit myapp1.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit myapp1.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 12 12:04:39 debian systemd[1]: Unit myapp1.service entered failed state.
```

Comment: Clearly there's been effort to debug this & the question includes _all_ the information we want & need to answer it.  That last is a valuable skill.  Well done and I hope your next task goes a little more smoothly :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install to `systemd/system` with a `.service` file extension; the executable bit does not need to be set.  Do not install systemd-format service files to `/etc/init.d/`; this is for legacy SysVinit style service scripts.

To start services, use `systemctl start myapp1`.  When you're not sure whether the service is implemented as systemd or SysV, use `service myapp1 start`.

To enable on boot [given an appropriate `Install` section] use `systemctl enable myapp1`.